# Цикл. JS Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, циклы

Это полностью рабочий код, который гуляет по ссылкам вперед, но я не могу понять как сделать такой же цикл, чтобы гулять в обратном порядке

```
$scope.nextId = function(id, a) {

    for (var i = 0; i< a.length; i++) {
      if (id == a[i].id) 
        if (i == a.length-1) { var next = '#/kitchens/'+a[0].id;  }
        else { next = '#/kitchens/'+a[i+1].id;}
    }
    console.log('next',next);
    return next;      
}
```

Это нерабочий, в обратном порядке

```
$scope.prevId = function(id, a) { 
for (var i = 0; i< a.length; i++) {
  if (id == a[i].id) 
    if (i == a[0]) { var prev = '#/kitchens/'+(a.length-1).id;  }
    else { prev = '#/kitchens/'+a[i-1].id; console.log(a);}
}    
return prev;
```

}

Это сама разметка

```
<a href="{{ prev }}" ng-click="prev = prevId(kitchen.id, kitchens)" style="color:green">NEXT</a>
<a href="{{ next }}" ng-click="next = nextId(kitchen.id, kitchens)" style="color:red">PREV</a>
```

Это котроллер (получаю каждую кухню в отдельном джейсон и весь массив кухонь в другом джейсон):

```
velesApp.controller('DetailCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
$scope.kitchenId = $routeParams.kitchenId;
var url = '/api/v1/kitchens/'+$routeParams.kitchenId; 
$http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.kitchen = data;  
});
$http.get('/api/v1/kitchens').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.kitchens = data;  
});
```

Поэтому Я вывожу биндингом отдельную кухню, т.к. на странице вывожу объект, а не массив всех кухонь. Т.е. ng-repeat нету в коде, биндингом вывожу

Comment: а в чем вопрос?

Comment: Уже исправил, вот

Comment: ну вообще алгоритм-то простой - ищем id текущего, и в зависимости от направления берем либо +1, либо -1, если выходит за границы - закольцовываем

Comment: приведите пример массива _а_

Comment: Вот я так и делаю, но показывает что a-1 undefiend. Прикреплю код обратного к вопросу

Comment: Кстати вполне возможно хранить не элемент, а индекс тоже. Можете показать разметку где и как вы используете этот метод?

Comment: ну вообще ошибка: `i == a[0])` - в функции _next_ сравниваете индексы, и все работает правильно, а здесь сравниваете индекс с элементам, поэтому и не работает

Comment: _kitchen_ это что-то полученное из _ng-repeat="kitchen in kitchens"_? если да, то код можно упростить

Comment: Да,  ng-repeat="kitchen in kitchens" ))

Comment: добавьте разметку, где это все вместе, тогда можно будет хороший ответ написать, а не просто про опечатку :-)

Comment: @andrey-fedorovich у вас же kitchens в `$scope`, зачем его параметром передавать? это раз. Вам не кажется странным объявление переменной внутри блока `if` (в отдном случае локально, в другом глобально), а потом возврат её как результат работы функции?

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, в яваскрипте область видимости переменной функцией ограничена, а не блоком `if`, по крайней мере когда используется _var_. и тут работает _hoisting_

Comment: @Grundy, наберите в консоли: function aa(a){ AAA = a; } aa('123'); console.log('typeof: '+typeof AAA);

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, набрал, вывелось _typeof: string_, что логично, так как переменная _AAA_ глобальная, а не локальная. я имел ввиду вот этот случай `function A(){
f=10;
var f;
return f;
} A();`, в этом случае вернется _10_, а `typeof f` - вернет _undefined_

Comment: @Grundy, это потому, что есть `var f`, но оно в исходном коде у вопрашающего завернуто в условие, которое теоретически может не отработать. Я обратил внимание на то, что так переменные объявлять не правильно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32782/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexey-lemesh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в строке

```
if (i == a[0])
```

здесь производится сравнение индекса со значением переменной, в данном случае объекта, поэтому всегда условие ложно.

Быстрая правка - `i == 0`, и внутри ветки
вместо `(a.length-1).id` -> `a[(a.length-1)].id`, так как *a.length-1* это число и у него нет поля *id*.

Вообще если присмотреться - функции отличаются незначительно, и можно их обобщить до одной функции с параметром

```
$scope.nextId = function(id, a, isNext) {
    var borderIndex=isNext? (a.length-1) : 0;
    var inc =isNext? 1 : -1;

    for (var i = 0; i< a.length; i++) {
      if (id == a[i].id) {
        if (i == borderIndex) { 
          var next = '#/kitchens/'+a[a.length-1-borderIndex].id;  
        }
        else { 
          next = '#/kitchens/'+a[i+inc].id;
        }
        //так как уже нашли, нет смысла бежать по циклу дальше
        console.log('next',next);// 
        return next;      
      } 
    }
}
```

Comment: работает, я счастлив

Comment: @AndreyFedorovich, надо просто повнимательнее быть чуть-чуть :-)